# Not able to run node in the terminal

Tags: javascript

I opened the terminal on my mac, and first checked that I have node installed: node -v
v14.17.5

I then tried to open a file I created index.html from Visual Studio Code and I got a throw err from the terminal. { The code:'Module_NOT_FOUND', requireStack:[] }

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: What *exactly* did you try?

Comment: Do you mean `index.js` ? Or did you try to run an html file with node ? Please clarify your question.

Comment: It is still not working if I change the file name to index.js I have two files saved on Visual Studio Code: index.html and index.js I also have terminal and iterm2 on my mac.  I pasted what I got from iterm2 node
Welcome to Node.js v14.17.5.
Type ".help" for more information.
> node index.js
node index.js
     ^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

node is a runtime environment that can execute javascript on a machine. So it can't read html file, but only js files. You can execute a js file with the following command in the terminal: `node index.js`

Et voilà.

Please note you can also write javascript directly in your terminal by entering a node environment.

```js
node
const a = "hello"
a

// return "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to run an html file using node
just change the index.html to index.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).